# Equation answer won't output to JTextField with using CoomboBox if statments

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jtextfield, jcombobox

I am very new to Java and am taking a Java 1 class. I am trying to use a JComboBox selection in an if statement and then display an answer based on the selection in a JTextField. It all compiled correctly but the answer will not display and I don't Know what i need to change. I've searched and tried several different things but none seemed to work.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class HayDyGuiTempConv extends JFrame
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new HayDyGuiTempConv();
}

private JButton buttonConvert;
private JButton exitButton;
private JTextField textAmount;
private String fieldText;
private JTextField field;



public HayDyGuiTempConv()
{

    this.setSize(440,150);
    this.setLocation(350,420);
    this.setTitle("Temperature Conversion");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    ButtonListener bl = new ButtonListener();
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.add(new JLabel("Enter temperature to convert: "));

    textAmount = new JTextField(6);
    panel1.add(textAmount);

    JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<> (new String[] {"C to F", "F to C"});
    comboBox.addActionListener(bl);
    panel1.add(comboBox);

    buttonConvert = new JButton("Convert");
    buttonConvert.addActionListener(bl);
    buttonConvert.setToolTipText("Convert the temperature.");
    panel1.add(buttonConvert);

    panel1.add(new JLabel("Temp: "));

    field = new JTextField(6);
    field.setEditable(false);
    panel1.add(field);

    exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
    exitButton.addActionListener(bl);
    exitButton.setToolTipText("Exit the program.");
    panel1.add(exitButton);

    this.add(panel1);

    this.setVisible(true);
}

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {


        if(e.getSource() == buttonConvert)
        {

            if(e.getSource() == ("C to F"))
            {
                double tempEntered = Double.parseDouble(textAmount.getText());
                double tempConverted = tempEntered - 32 * (5/9);
                String tempAmount = (Double.toString(tempConverted));
                field.setText(tempAmount);
            }
            else if(e.getSource() == ("F to C"))
            {
                double tempEntered = Double.parseDouble(textAmount.getText());
                double tempConverted = tempEntered * (9/5) + 32;
                String tempAmount = (String.format("%.2f",(tempConverted)));
                field.setText(tempAmount);
            }
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == exitButton)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Edit : I tried both suggestions and with both of them when I type in an number and try to convert I get this in the interactions pane: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JButton cannot be cast to javax.swing.JComboBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(e.getSource() == ("C to F"))
```

The "source" of the event is a component, not a String. In this case it is the `JComboBox`.

You want to test the selected value of the combo box so the code should be something like:

```
JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
int index = comboBox.getSelectedIndex();

If (index == 0)
    //  do C to F conversion
else
    //  do F to C conversion
```

Also, don't use "==" to compare String values. In the future for String comparison you use the `equals(...)` method of the String.

Edit:

I thought you were adding the ActionListener to the combobox. Then you can just automatically do the conversion when the item is selected from the combo box. There is no need for the button.

If you want to keep the button then you need to define your combo box as an instance variable in your class. Then you can just access the combo box by name.

Comment: I edited my code with your suggestion and now I get  a lot of red text when I try to convert that says JButton cannot be cast to javax.swing.JComboBox.

Here is the exception : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JButton cannot be cast to javax.swing.JComboBox

Comment: Thanks so much. I needed to keep the button so I added the instance variable and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use == when comparing Strings as this will not compare the values but the instances.

Get the String value of comboBox with comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
and then compare them with the .equals() method.

Mostly the == will be used to compare numbers or instances;

```
String selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();

if(selected.equals("C to F")){
//  do C to F conversion
}else{
//  do F to C conversion
}
```

Comment: I edited my code with your suggestion and now I get a lot of red text when I try to convert that says JButton cannot be cast to javax.swing.JComboBox. Here is the exception : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JButton cannot be cast to javax.swing.JComboBox –